# Is It Possible To Use A Cursor With Key-Only Queries?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I was wondering if it's possible to use a cursor on an keys-only query to the datastore, after hours of looking and seeing if there was a workaround, I got nothing.

The reason that I want to do this is because I want to save on datastore reads by caching these entities in memcache.

I have the following query using Objectify:

```
Query<EventEntity> query = ofy().load().type(EventEntity.class).filter(combinedFilter).order("time").limit(50);

if(cursor != null){
    query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
}

QueryResultIterator<EventEntity> iterator = query.iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

So i was being "not smart" and the answer is actually very simple just call `keys()` after creating the query and before the iterator.

```
Query<EventEntity> query = ofy().load().type(EventEntity.class).filter(combinedFilter).order("time").limit(50);

if(cursor != null){
    query = query.startAt(Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursor));
}

*QueryResultIterator<EventEntity> iterator = query.keys().iterator();*
```